# I got an image on terminal from the output of homebrew package manager

Tags: terminal, homebrew, internationalization

I got a strange image from the output of brew like this [image]. I'm curious about this behaviour. Is this a feature of brew or the image comes from some special character set? If a character in some character set, I think it can be employed to customise the terminal (prompt, etc.).

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: It is a new feature of brew. Not all characters/emojis can be properly printed in a pleasant manner though. Some might not print properly and some might not print at all. I have not gone through all characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be an emoji. You can insert them anywhere by clicking Edit > Special Characters > Emoji. The beer one is under the Objects subcategory.[image]